# Please help me identify this bulbous plant with long, broad leaves and white flowers

Tags: identification, flowering, perennials, bulbs

I rescued this plant from a landfill in Johannesburg, South Africa. It has taken well in my garden and is blooming in just the second season that it's been here.

When I rescued it, I thought it was Agapanthus. But the flower is not right. My mom suggested it may be Amaryllis, but the flower and the flower stalk are not right. The stamens are attached to the edges of the petals, they do not come up the centre of the flower as do Amaryllis, and the flower stalk is flattened, it is not as round as Amaryllis.

p.s. It's Spring here, that may help with identification.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a [Peruvian Daffodil](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1234/) *Hymenocallis festalis* The curious stamen arrangement matches up, as do the flowers and leaves. Your first guess as well as your mother's guess were in the right genetic ballpark. Agapanthus, Amaryllis and Hymenocallis are all genera of the Amaryllidaceae family.

Comment: That looks almost exactly right. I think the family is closer than what I've had so far. But the long thin petals on my flower are not as elaborate as Hymenocallis festalis. My flower looks a little closer to Hymenocallis 'Advance' (http://www.pacificbulbsociety.org/pbswiki/index.php/IsmeneHybrids) which is a hybrid of Hymenocallis.